# TypeScript + React: enforce correct ref props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

I just got bitten by a runtime exception because I passed a React ref into the wrong component.

I wonder if/how TypeScript could have saved my bacon here?

Reduced test case:

```
import * as React from 'react';

class Modal extends React.Component<{}> {
    close = () => {};
}

declare const modal: Modal;

modal.close();

const modalRef = React.createRef<Modal>();

// Let's try giving this ref to the correct component…
// No error as expected :-)
<Modal ref={modalRef} />;

class SomeOtherComponent extends React.Component<{}> {}

// Let's try giving this ref to the wrong component…
// Expected type error but got none! :-(
<SomeOtherComponent ref={modalRef} />;

// Now when we try to use this ref, TypeScript tells us it's safe to do so.
// But it's not, because the ref has been incorrectly assigned to another component!
if (modalRef.current !== null) {
    modalRef.current.close() // runtime error!
}
```

Comment: Can you type your `modalRef` as a `Modal`? `const modalRef:Modal = ... `

Comment: No, because refs are a unique type. (They have a property called `current`.)

Comment: How about `React.RefObject<Modal>` ?

Comment: That doesn't change anything, because that's the same type as returned by `createRef` in my example.

Comment: TypeScrip do not capture all error. As you can assign a string to a wrong function as well. It is correct syntactically.  But not correct semantically. I just use ``React.createRef<ReactInstance>()`` in similar cases. This way both component is just a react instance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why aren't getting any errors with ref is in the fact that both your components are derivatives of the same base class *React.Component* in your example, but they don't have any differing properties and don't have an explicit interface.

Check a section on type compatibility in Typescript:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

As Typescript uses structural instead of nominal subtyping, classes can be merged and compared as equal in the following scenarios:

- Both have the same property members
- Neither has any property members (not a realistic case, but it is the one that you have)
- One class can have members that other one doesn't have, but ONLY if it has all of the properties from the other class. E.g. it can add stuff, but not introduce new things
- Constructors can differ
- You can also redefine the same property member

In all other cases, they are not compatible.

In case you rewrite to:

`React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();`

You will clearly be able to see that refs are outlined as incompatible on your components for example.

This is because React.Component is not in any way compatible with HTMLElement type (which HTMLInputElement is a derivative off e.g. these classses have different properties).

It's not that this assertion doesn't work, it's more of a case of how exactly it works under the hood, which follows the rules outlined on top.

**Back to the issue at hand**

You can do several things to avoid these kinds of issues, dependant on your situation,

*You have 2 components, with differing react props.*

In case your components have differing props, create interfaces for both, and you will not have this issue, as it will return a type error that Props on these components don't match which is true.

*You have 2 components, with no custom react properties*

Your current problem. In case you add a new property member to **SomeOtherComponent** that doesn't exist in class **Modal**, for example, `open = () =>`, then they will be resolved as different.

**Summary**

In case you can't add an interface, and you don't have differing property members in these 2 classes, then it is realistic enough that this is the same class.

You just need to figure out a better way how to use it for both scenarios.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, thank you. It's a shame that my only option is to add a fake prop to a component which doesn't really need any props—but at least that's an option. I wish TypeScript had a better solution to this, as it seems a common use case to me.

Comment: No problem. Yes, type inference in TS is not ideal, but it is still good enough for most scenarios. The question here is really why are your classes so similar that they pass type inference with the ref scenario, and can they be merged into 1 single class, but it's hard to tell without the real example.

Comment: Update: I submitted a suggestion to TS https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31798

Answer (score -1):

Possible solutions is to use interface for class and ref.

```js
interface IModal {
  close(): void;
}

class Modal extends React.Component<{}> implements IModal {
    close = () => {};
}

const modalRef = React.createRef<IModal>();

<Modal ref={modalRef as React.RefObject<Modal>}/>
<SomeOtherComponent ref={modalRef} />
// Type 'RefObject<IModal>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: //SomeOtherComponent | null) => void) | RefObject<SomeOtherComponent> | null | undefined'.
//  Type 'RefObject<IModal>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<SomeOtherComponent>'.
//    Type 'IModal' is missing the following properties from type 'SomeOtherComponent': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 3 more.  TS2322
```

Comment: That then requires a type assertion in the valid case, which is bad practice. I have to be careful to only use the type assertion when it's technically valid to do so. What's to stop me from doing `<SomeOtherComponent ref={modalRef as React.RefObject<Modal>} />;`?

Comment: as well as nothing stops you from writing `ref={modalRef as any}` in case of correct Typescript type assertions.

Comment: @IgorTkachuk casting a type will not resolve a runtime error. It is a compiler hack, that should be avoided whenever possible. Also, casting as any should ideally never be used (except casting to an object, where any is preferred over object). On the other hand, casting both types to any will not resolve the issue here, as they are already the same "similar" type, so it would be a step back, not forward.